# I can't debug a functional test for a custom module

Tags: testing

I am trying to debug the functional tests for my custom module.
When I run the debugger, it doesn't hit the breakpoint I've set on the first line of the test method. However, when I debug a functional test from the Node module, it works.

Comment: Have you tried using xdebug_break() at your breakpoint? Often helps because it forces a break even if the mapping is not correct (which sounds like a possible reason for this issue)

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: The mappings would have to be correct for the Node module to be debugged. PHPStorm uses the parent mapping for its sub directories and files. So as long as my structure matches (it does) then it shouldn't be a mapping issue.

Comment: In that case it sounds like your code is not being executed. So that should be the focus of your efforts now, I guess.

Comment: Alright, so if I don't run the debugger and instead just run the test. The test does get executed and comes back as passed with multiple assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open PHPStorm and go to file > Invalidate Caches...

Comment: I  think the question needs a few adjustments if this is the answer.